# How to get user specific exception details in case of multi user system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

Suppose in an application at a time multiple users are online. And because of some reason 4 users got exceptions. As we have global exception handling implemented in our Global.asax file, so we show a custom error page to all the user and log the error using below code:

```
var currentException = Server.GetLastError();
logger.LogDetails(currentException); // some logging code
Server.ClearError();
```

1. User 1 got Divide by zero exception.
2. User 2 got invalid cast exception.
3. User 3 got Index out of range exception.
4. User 4 got some Sqlexception.

What will this Server.GetLastError() return in this case? 
Also, I need to log the exceptions. So think of it as, I want to log exception based on user as key and Exception details as description. So for User 1, there will be a log entry something like User=U1, ExceptionDescription="Divide By zero".

As Steve suggested in comments, I can get current user using HTTPContext but still not able to get exception that is occurred in their session. How can I achieve this?

Comment: all 4 of them, 4 times

Comment: then how can I get user specific exception details, that I need to log?

Comment: I guess you can check httpcontext to see which user is it

Comment: But still Server.GetLastError will not return random exception not specific to current user.

Comment: don't really understand your question. The context will be the current user or otherwise how are you going to redirect the right user to the right error screen

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. As I mentioned in my question, I need to log the exceptions. So think of it as, I want to log exception based on user. So for User 1, there will be a log entry something like User=U1, ExceptionDescription="Divide By zero". Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @sunil20000: Use my open source error handling service to get everything done for you: http://onetrueerror.com

Comment: @jgauffin our requirement is very simple we don't need whole package for it. If I can get last exception specific to every user that is more than enough for me. If you have any idea about it, then all the comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be worried that GetLastError will return whatever error occured last regardless of user, and if four users get an error there could be crosstalk and they could see each other's errors (or the logging code may log the wrong user name with the wrong error).  This is not the case.

[GetLastError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426035/proper-handling-of-getlasterror-and-others-in-a-multithreaded-context) is session-specific, or more precisely, thread-specific.  It will return only the error triggered by the user who is receiving the response from the current thread.

> GetLastError Function
>
> Retrieves the calling thread's last-error code value. The last-error code is maintained on a per-thread basis. Multiple threads do not overwrite each other's last-error code.

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(VS.85).aspx)

So just use Steve's answer and you should be good to go.

Comment: All the links that you have shared are related to C++, and in my case it's C#. So just wanted to confirm that both are same or Server,GetlastError() in C# is different from GetLastError function of C++?

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentException = Server.GetLastError();
var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
logger.LogDetails(currentException, user); // some logging code
Server.ClearError();
```

you can just get the user before you log it and that will be the current user for the error.